# Im trying to make a discord bot that checks if a user is playing a specific game

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js 14.7.1. I also cant find any fixes with the official documentation.

I tried using the presenceUpdate event put it somehow doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the current user by fetching it with his specific ID. Afterwards you have to checkout the Discord.Js Documentation at [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Presence?scrollTo=status). Following the [Activites](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity) you see the prop '.name' (The activity's name).

I don't know how you want to use the status, but i can provide you a example for checking the Status and Activity of the specific user for the bot login:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "";
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("ready");
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID); // Replace with the ID of the guild
  guild.members
    .fetch(USER_ID) // Replace with the ID of the specific User
    .then((member) => {
      if (
        member.presence.activities &&
        member.presence.activities.state === "PLAYING"
      ) {
        console.log(
          `${member.user.tag} is currently playing ${member.presence.activities.name}`
        );
      } else if (member.presence.status) {
        console.log(
          `${member.user.tag} is not currently playing a game, Status: ${member.presence.status}`
        );
      } else {
        console.log(`${member.user.tag} is not currently playing a game`);
      }
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: i tried the code and I got this output "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')"

Comment: Maybe you did not cached the right GUILD_ID (your server ID), See https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=members for more informations.

Comment: Also please edit your question with the code that causes your problem so we can help you.